# SOAP Web Service Response different on SOAPUI and C#.NET

Tags: c#, soapui, soap-client, ibm-integration-bus

I am using IBM Integration Bus for my middle ware, as I have developed an integration service (SOAP Web Service) on it which is successfulllu integrated with database and using ESQL Compute Node in message flow I have called database function which return data;

```
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:SD_GetAccountAvailableLimitResponse.SD_GetAccountAvailableLimitResponse = 
        PASSTHRU('SELECT * FROM SampleDB.DBO.FUNC_GET_Data(''haxan'',''11335544'')');
```

This returned correct and full data contain multiple records.
Now the second part which has the issue/problem. I am calling this SOAP Web Service in C#.NET application and add this as a Web Reference. As my C# Code is

```
IS_ServiceHttpService httpRequest = new IS_ServiceHttpService();
        SD_GetAccountAvailableLimit obj = new SD_GetAccountAvailableLimit();
        obj.sAccountNumber = "11335544";
        obj.sChannelID = "20";
        obj.sSambaDigital_Username = "haxan";
        obj.sUserID = "tcib";
        obj.sPassword = "TcibSamba";
        obj.sChannelID = "20";
SD_GetAccountAvailableLimitResponse response = httpRequest.SD_GetAccountAvailableLimit(obj);
```

Here is the problem in Response !, when I test this Serive on SOAPUI it will return more than one records according to database query inside function but when I call this in C# as above; the response contain only first record (Very first row). I am badly confused why this is happening, please help me out in this. Thanks

Comment: These seem to be different queries that would have different result sets, why would you expect them to return the same number of records?

Comment: Because I am passing same parameters as in SOAPUI so the number of records should be same !

Comment: They do not at all look the same based on what you have posted.

Comment: Now corrected, I have checked with the same parameters on SOAPUI and C#.NET code SOAPUI return multiple records but C#.NET return first record only (First Row).